# Can Infant Crocodiles digest Bread?

Tags: reptile

I'm just curious as to whether crocodiles and if you require specifics, saltwater crocodiles, could eat bread as infants. I was watching Lake Placid and I was curious as to whether infant saltwater crocodiles could even digest bread.

Comment: From a quick search it seems that amylase production in reptiles is highly variable and is generally a function of the eating habits. According to that logic crocodiles shouldnt produce amylase. Therefore I shall guess that crocs cant digest bread

Comment: This question seems more suitable for Pets-SE

Comment: If @WYSIWYG could convert his comment in an answer I think this is an OK question. I haven't seen much folks holding a croc as pet ;)